Update mysql database from updating individual cells
Hi I am developing a project locally and started from this https://codepen.io/fjfalah/pen/WEppVa to create my table linked to my mysql database. I have had no problems in displaying the data but I am experiencing problems in updating the data. Once I edit and update the table I display the message "Record successfully updated" but it doesn't actually update anything and I don't have any error messages in both console and logs. I am trying to update only two columns but actually all of them will have to be modified. I will share the code with you, thanks for any suggestions.
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Admin</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap 5 CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> 
        
        <script src="https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/assets/js/tabledit.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="title-container">
                <h1>Aggiornamento Prezzi</h1>
                <h2> <?= $user_name ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="users-container">
                <h2></h2>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <div class="position-relative content">
                        <div class="position-absolute w-100 row" style="z-index: 50;">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="filter-wrapper">
                                    <input type="radio" class="filter-checkbox" name="filter" data-filter="" value="Tutto" checked="checked" />
                                    Tutto
                                    <input type="radio" class="filter-checkbox" name="filter" data-filter="Antintrusione" value="Antintrusione" />
                                    Antintrusione
                                    <input type="radio" class="filter-checkbox" name="filter" data-filter="Antincendio" value="Antincendio" />
                                    Antincendio
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <table id="sample_data" class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col"> Prodotti ID</th>
                                <th scope="col">Nome Prodotto</th>
                                <th scope="col">Gamma</th>
                                <th scope="col">Alfanumerico</th>
                                <th scope="col">Descrizione</th>
                                <th scope="col">Assorbimento</th>
                                <th scope="col">Icona 1</th>
                                <th scope="col">Icona 2</th>
                                <th scope="col">Icona 3</th>
                                <th scope="col">Icona 4</th>
                                <th scope="col">Icona 5</th>
                                <th scope="col">Immagine</th>
                                <th scope="col">Garanzia</th>
                                <th scope="col">Riparazione</th>
                                <th scope="col">Costo Acquisto</th>
                                <th scope="col">Prezzo Vendita</th>
                                <th scope="col">Stato</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php 
                            $var = @$_POST['ProdottiID'] ;
                            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `prodotti`");
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

                            foreach ($result as $row) {
                                $ProdottiID = $row['ProdottiID'];
                                $NomeProdotto = $row['NomeProdotto'];
                                $Gamma = $row['Gamma'];
                                $Alfanumerico = $row['Alfanumerico'];
                                $Descrizione = $row['Descrizione'];
                                $Assorbimento = $row['Assorbimento'];
                                $Icona1 = $row['Icona1'];
                                $Icona2 = $row['Icona2'];
                                $Icona3 = $row['Icona3'];
                                $Icona4 = $row['Icona4'];
                                $Icona5 = $row['Icona5'];
                                $Immagine = $row['Immagine'];
                                $Garanzia = $row['Garanzia'];
                                $Riparazione = $row['Riparazione'];
                                $CostoAcquisto = $row['CostoAcquisto'];
                                $PrezzoVendita = $row['PrezzoVendita'];
                                $Stato = $row['Stato'];
                            ?>
                          <tr>
                            <td id="ProdottiID" scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $ProdottiID ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td id="NomeProdotto" scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $NomeProdotto ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $Gamma ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td id="Alfanumerico" scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $Alfanumerico ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $Descrizione ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $Assorbimento ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $Icona1 ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $Icona2 ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $Icona3 ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $Icona4 ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $Icona5 ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $Immagine ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $Garanzia ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $Riparazione ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $CostoAcquisto ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $PrezzoVendita ?></span><div></div></td>
                            <td scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $Stato ?></span><div></div></td>
                        </tr>
                                                      <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <script>
        $('table tbody').on('dblclick', 'td', function(){
    var valCell = $(this).find('span').text();
    
    $(this).find('span').hide();
    $(this).find('div').show().html('\
      <div class="input-group">\
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+valCell+'">\
        <span class="input-group-btn">\
          <button id="save" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="bi bi-check2"></i></button>\
          <button id="close" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="bi bi-x-circle"></i></button>\
        </span>\
      </div>');
    $(this).find('input').focus();
    $(this).closest('tbody').find('td').not($(this)).each(function(){
      $(this).find('span').show();
      $(this).find('div').hide();
    });
  }); 
  
  $('table').on('click','#close',function(){
    $(this).closest('td').find('span.value').show();
    $(this).closest('div').hide();
  });
    $('table').on('click','#close',function(){
    $(this).closest('td').find('span.value').show();
    $(this).closest('div').hide();
  });
  $('table').on('click','#save', function(){
     var getValueInput = $(this).closest('div').find('input').val();
    $(this).closest('td').find('span.value').text(getValueInput);
    
    $(this).closest('td').find('span.value').show();
    $(this).closest('div').hide();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "conn/action2.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {ProdottiID: $('#ProdottiID').val(), NomeProdotto: $('#NomeProdotto').val(), Alfanumerico: $('#Alfanumerico').val()},
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
          alert("Record successfully updated");
        }
    });
  });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>

This is the php file for updating the database
<?php

//action2.php


$NomeProdotto = $_POST['NomeProdotto']; 
$Alfanumerico = $_POST['Alfanumerico'];
$ProdottiID = $_POST['ProdottiID'];

//You need create a database connection
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '11111';
$dbpass = '22222';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, "lslistini2");

if(! $conn ){
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$retval = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE prodotti SET ProdottiID = '$ProdottiID', NomeProdotto = '$NomeProdotto', Alfanumerico = '$Alfanumerico' WHERE ProdottiID = '$ProdottiID'");

if(! $retval ) {
   die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysqli_close($conn);


?>

Thanks again for your help

You are trying to read .val() from table cell elements there to try and build the data set to send to the server. Table cells do not have a "value".

With the browser deverloper tools you can see what you send to your PHP script. Learning how to use them will save you loads of time. Also: Why do you set ProdottiID twice in your update query? And read this page about SQL-injection.

fyi, id attributes must be unique, you have multiple elements with the same id after running your loop - which is invalid

@kiko-software Yes, I verified via console and it is empty

@CBroe Thank you for your comment, could you explain more? Thank you

You need to read the values from the actual input fields you are inserting into those cells.

@CBroe The cells have a value, because I read it from the database. where am I going wrong? I don't understand

Just because an element has some content, doesn't mean it has a "value", in the sense that term is used when it comes to HTML. Only form input fields have a value, that you can read via jQuery's .val().

But by double-clicking the cells become input is not enough?

$('#ProdottiID') (and $('#NomeProdotto') and $('#Alfanumerico')) would only ever return the first element with that id. As mentioned, ids must be unique

@brombeer The id is always different is the primary key in the database and each row will have its own, I don't understand how can I make it different?

<td id="ProdottiID" f.e. will duplicate in your loop

Note that your code is wide open to SQL injection. Always use prepared statements, never use variables directly in a SQL query string.

If the table cell doesn't contain an <input>, use .text() rather than .val() to get the contents.

@Barmar Yes, on double click the cell becomes an input...I'll give it a try anyway

This question is similar to: How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If the linked question does not help: did you check whether this is a PHP problem, a jQuery problem, or a MySQL problem? Does the updated data reach the PHP script? Does the UPDATE query itself work properly?

@NicoHaase How are they similar? This question is about getting the values from the HTML, not about how to use them in the PHP query.

I inserted the explanation in the comments for both the frontend and the backend
ps. consider using parametric queries, because action2.php is full of vulnerabilities
<html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Admin</title>
            <!-- Bootstrap 5 CSS -->
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
            
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> 
            
            <script src="https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/assets/js/tabledit.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="main">
                <div class="title-container">
                    <h1>Aggiornamento Prezzi</h1>
                    <h2> <?= $user_name ?></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="users-container">
                    <h2></h2>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <div class="position-relative content">
                            <div class="position-absolute w-100 row" style="z-index: 50;">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <div class="filter-wrapper">
                                        <input type="radio" class="filter-checkbox" name="filter" data-filter="" value="Tutto" checked="checked" />
                                        Tutto
                                        <input type="radio" class="filter-checkbox" name="filter" data-filter="Antintrusione" value="Antintrusione" />
                                        Antintrusione
                                        <input type="radio" class="filter-checkbox" name="filter" data-filter="Antincendio" value="Antincendio" />
                                        Antincendio
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <table id="sample_data" class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col"> Prodotti ID</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Nome Prodotto</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Gamma</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Alfanumerico</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Descrizione</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Assorbimento</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Icona 1</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Icona 2</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Icona 3</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Icona 4</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Icona 5</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Immagine</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Garanzia</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Riparazione</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Costo Acquisto</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Prezzo Vendita</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Stato</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php 
                                
                                $var = @$_POST['ProdottiID'] ;
                                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `prodotti`");
                                $stmt->execute();
                                $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
                                
                                foreach ($result as $row) {
                                    $ProdottiID = $row['ProdottiID'];
                                    $NomeProdotto = $row['NomeProdotto'];
                                    $Gamma = $row['Gamma'];
                                    $Alfanumerico = $row['Alfanumerico'];
                                    $Descrizione = $row['Descrizione'];
                                    $Assorbimento = $row['Assorbimento'];
                                    $Icona1 = $row['Icona1'];
                                    $Icona2 = $row['Icona2'];
                                    $Icona3 = $row['Icona3'];
                                    $Icona4 = $row['Icona4'];
                                    $Icona5 = $row['Icona5'];
                                    $Immagine = $row['Immagine'];
                                    $Garanzia = $row['Garanzia'];
                                    $Riparazione = $row['Riparazione'];
                                    $CostoAcquisto = $row['CostoAcquisto'];
                                    $PrezzoVendita = $row['PrezzoVendita'];
                                    $Stato = $row['Stato'];
                                ?>
                                
                              <tr>
                                <?php 
                                foreach($row as $k=>$v){ 
                                  /* 
                                  put your data as attribute on td so you can retrieve them inside your dbl click event 
                                  
                                  i've used:
                                  data-row-id => the id to use in your "where condition" 
                                  data-name   => the field name to edit
                                  data-value  => the value to set
                                  */
                                ?>
                                  <td data-row-id='<?= $ProdottiID ?>' data-name='<?= $k ?>' data-value='<?= $v ?>' scope="col"><span class="value"><?= $v ?></span><div></div></td>
                                <?php } ?>
                              </tr>
                              <?php } ?>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <script>
            $('table tbody').on('dblclick', 'td', function(){
            var valCell = $(this).find('span').text();
            
            $(this).find('span').hide();
            $(this).find('div').show().html('\
              <div class="input-group">\
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+valCell+'">\
                <span class="input-group-btn">\
                  <button id="save" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="bi bi-check2"></i></button>\
                  <button id="close" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="bi bi-x-circle"></i></button>\
                </span>\
              </div>');
            $(this).find('input').focus();
            $(this).closest('tbody').find('td').not($(this)).each(function(){
              $(this).find('span').show();
              $(this).find('div').hide();
            });
          }); 
          
          $('table').on('click','#close',function(){
            $(this).closest('td').find('span.value').show();
            $(this).closest('div').hide();
          });
            $('table').on('click','#close',function(){
            $(this).closest('td').find('span.value').show();
            $(this).closest('div').hide();
          });
          $('table').on('click','#save', function(){
            //WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING 
            // theoretically it is possible to also change the value of the id, but I don't think it is wise
            //WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING 
            var getValueInput = $(this).closest('div').find('input').val();
            const hero=$(this).closest('td');
            hero.find('span.value').text(getValueInput);
            hero.find('span.value').show();
            $(this).closest('div').hide();
            
            
            
       
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "conn/action2.php",
                //url:"test_res.php",
                method: "POST",
                //here you retrive what you need from attributes if you need more info you can pass them in the same way
                data: {ProdottiID: hero.attr("data-row-id"), NomeCampo: hero.attr("data-name"), ValoreCampo: getValueInput, VecchioValoreCampo: hero.attr("data-value")},
                cache: false,
                success: function(response)
                {
                  console.dir(response);
                  alert("Record successfully updated");
                }
            });
            
          });
          </script>
        </body>
    </html>

action2.php:
<?php
//action2.php

//since on your frontend  you are sending data "on col change" you can edit  a single field at time
//if you want update the full row you need to rethink the frontend for edit the whole row before you send ajax data



$NomeCampo = $_POST['NomeCampo'] ?? ""; 
$ValoreCampo = $_POST['ValoreCampo'] ?? "";
$ProdottiID = $_POST['ProdottiID'] ?? "";

if(!is_numeric($ProdottiID)){
  die("something wrong with ID");
}

if(!preg_match("/[a-z_0-9]+/i", $NomeCampo)){
  die("something wrong with NomeCampo");
}

//die(json_encode($_POST));


//You need create a database connection
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '11111';
$dbpass = '22222';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, "lslistini2");

if(! $conn ){
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

//DANGER DANGER DANGER DANGER DANGER DANGERDANGER DANGER DANGER
//DANGER DANGER DANGER DANGER DANGER DANGERDANGER DANGER DANGER

//careful here because i see injection everywhere===========================================================================================
$retval = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE prodotti SET ProdottiID = '$ProdottiID', $NomeCampo = '$ValoreCampo' WHERE ProdottiID = '$ProdottiID'");
//careful here because i see injection everywhere===========================================================================================

//DANGER DANGER DANGER DANGER DANGER DANGERDANGER DANGER DANGER
if(! $retval ) {
   die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysqli_close($conn);


?>

